# jquery ajax call to google maps keeps page loading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I know I didn't use the right terminology here but when I load this page, in the upper left in Firefox it says the data is still trying to load, yet it shows me the right data.

**Why would this script below cause this error and not complete the call?**

**Second question:** What are the best terms to describe this action of "not loading" and still showing the spinning icon in browser?

Here is the full code:

```
<?

$geoLong = $_POST[geoLong];
$geoLat = $_POST[geoLat];



?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() 
{
    $.ajax({ url:'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=<? echo "$geoLong,$geoLat";?>&sensor=true',
             success: function(data){
                 document.write("City="+data.results[0].address_components[3].long_name);
                 document.write("&Country="+data.results[0].address_components[6].long_name);
                 /*or you could iterate the components for only the city and state*/
                  }
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure it is your code that is still running and not some social plugin or an image? You should check with firebug what request has not finished yet. Also, using `document.write` is not going to work; where would the text be written, after the html closing tag?

Comment: document.write works. I am actually using that code to send back to a call from actionscript from a phone. The call works. I am thinking it may be a virus in firefox because lately other windows have been opening. Also, I don't get this error in google chrome.